# How to write test cases for useAsyncDebounce of react table?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Below is the snapshot of my search filter code of table component(react-table). I'm trying to cover test cases for unreachable code using jest. Is their anyway to cover test cases for onAsyncDebounceChange method?

```
import { React, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { useAsyncDebounce } from "react-table";
import { Label, Input } from "reactstrap";
import { isValidSearchInput } from "./helper"

// Component for Global Filter
export function GlobalFilter({ globalFilter, setGlobalFilter }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(globalFilter);

  const onChange = value => {
    if (isValidSearchInput(value)) {
        setValue(value);
        onAsyncDebounceChange(value);
    }
  };

  const onAsyncDebounceChange = useAsyncDebounce(value => {
        setGlobalFilter (value);
  }, 500);

  return (
    <div>
      <Label>Search Table: </Label>
      <Input
        value={value || ""}
        onChange={(e) => {
          onChange(e.target.value);
        }}
        placeholder=" Enter value "
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: do you have any updates on this ?

Comment: Nope, it's still in TODO state.